# How do I update a column of a table which picks values from a default null valued column of another table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables user and user_secondary. I have to fetch few columns and store in user_secondary. Now the two tables have a row let's say - gender which a user may update later and then save it. But this entry was stored as null in user_secondary. Now I have to update this gender field against the user in my user_secondary table. How do I do it?

Cannot define key constraints as the gender field is null valued.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excuse me, just how the two table are related? Anyway this code might act as a sample:

```
UPDATE user_secondary
SET user_secondary.GENDER = (SELECT user1.usergender FROM user1 
                             WHERE user1.userid = user_secondary.id)
where user_secondary.GENDER IS NULL
```

Comment: 1st table, i didn't put user because it's common.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE user_secondary
JOIN user ON user.id=user_secondary.id 
SET user_secondary.gender=user.gender 
WHERE user_secondary.gender IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through every user row and if the field is empty, do a simple query to fetch it from the user_secondary table. Then use that data to run an update statement on the user table.